# Preferencias en un navigation drawer

Tags: android

Tengo una actividad con un `navigation drawer` en la que si se pincha en una de las opciones debería cargar el fragmento de preferencias. Para ello hago lo siguiente pero no me permite cargar el `PreferenceFragment` con `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.centro_list_frag,  new Settings.Configuracion()).commit();
```

En toda la aplicación utilizo `getSupportFragmentManager()` por lo que en este caso tengo que utilizarlo también ya que si utilizo `getFragmentManager()` no carga el fragmento correcto al pinchar en el resto de opciones del `navigation drawer`.

La actividad de preferencias y su fragmento es el siguiente:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.configuracion, new Configuracion());
    ft.commit();

}
  public static class Configuracion extends PreferenceFragment{

    public Configuracion() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencia);
    }
}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:


            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

¿Cómo podría cargar el fragmento de preferencias con `navigation drawer`?

Así cargo las opciones en el navigation drawer:

```
            private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
    Fragment1 fragmentoGenerico=null;
    Fragment2 fragmentoGenerico2=null;
    switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.item_todos:

            fragmentoGenerico = new Fragment1();
            if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {


                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.centro_list_frag, fragmentoGenerico).commit();


            }

            break;
        case R.id.item_ninguno:

            fragmentoGenerico2 = new Fragment2();
            if (fragmentoGenerico2 != null) {


                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.centro_list_frag, fragmentoGenerico2).commit();

            }
            break;
}
```

Comment: He añadido a mi pregunta la clase modificada. Sigue ocurriendo lo mismo

Comment: ya ví lo que tratas de realizar, no estaba bien indentado tu código, dentro de la actividad es una clase que extiende PreferenceFragment, lo cual se puede realizar. Agrego una respuesta!

Comment: Si tienes problemas Agrega de que forma intentas abrir la actividad desde tu NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 1):

Si revisamos la documentación  **[PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)** extiende de [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), específicamente  de  `android.app.Fragment` y no de `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` por esa razón no se puede usar [getSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()).

Esta sería la forma correcta y más simplificada para cargar el [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html):

```
    //Carga PreferenceFragment
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new Configuracion()).commit();
```

Esta sería la Activity:

```
public class PrefActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         //Carga PreferenceFragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new Configuracion()).commit();

    }

    public static class Configuracion extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Carga preferencias de recurso xml.
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencia);
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto no debes tener problema para cargar el **[PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando pones new Configuration() ¿que sería el fragmento de la actividad de preferencias?

Comment: perdón @adamista ya corregí la respuesta, debe ser la clase que extiende de PreferenceFragment y esta dentro de la activity!

Comment: He probado así y carga el fragmento pero no se corresponde la opción que se clicka en el navigation drawer con la que se carga. ¿Puede que sea porque en el resto de opciones del navigation drawer se cargan con supportFragment?

Comment: agrega el código de como tratas de cargar las opciones con el Navigation Drawer por favor :)

Comment: Ya lo he añadido